# Find next highest number with the same digits

Tags: python, optimization

**Question**:

> Given any integer, efficiently find the next highest integer that uses the same digits. For example if the number is `15432`, you should return `21345`.

**Program**: I have written a program which automatically generates a random number in the range `random.randint(999, 999999)`:

```
print "Find the Next highest number!"
# Find the next highest digit which needs to be corrected.
# Two step approach.
#########
# Step1. Check all the digits expect the highest digit.
#        Whether that needs to be corrected. 
#        If yes, place next higest digit and sort the remaning digits after the placed
#        digit.

#########
# Step2
# The highest digit needs to be changed. 
# This occurs when all the remaning digit except the highest digit is in decending order
# Perform the following task
#  1. Shift rotate the number right by one digit. i.e. place the last digit  to the 
#     hightest index and shift the current highest digit once place right.
#  2. sort the remaning digits in the acending order.
#  3. Join the digits in index 0 and 1 with the sorted list in step2
#  eg: 15432
#  1.  21543
#  2.  345 
#  3.  21345

import sys
import random
number = random.randint(999,999999)
stringArr = str(number)
numberList = list(stringArr) # Given Number converted in list format
str_excpet_highest_digit = stringArr[1:]
array_excpet_highest_digit = list(str_excpet_highest_digit)
correct_Index = -1 
correct_Digit = -1 # current digit what is moved from the existing index 
digit_Moved = -1 # digit what is moved in to the correct index location
highestDigitChanged = -1 

###### Functions #######
def swapDigitAtInidix(fromIndex,toIndex,array):
    temp = array[fromIndex]
    array[fromIndex] = array[toIndex]
    array[toIndex] = temp
    return array # end function

def sortRemainingList(startIndex,array):
    sortedList = []
    temp = []
    for i in range(startIndex):
        sortedList.append(array[i])    
    for j in range(startIndex,len(array)):
        temp.append(array[j]) 

    # sort the right part of the list
    temp=sorted(temp)
    convertToString1 = ''.join(sortedList)
    convertToString2 = ''.join(temp)
    sortedString = convertToString1 + convertToString2
    sortedList = list(sortedString)
    print "Number except the highest digit:",sortedList
    return sortedList # end function

# This will check the highest digit to be replaced. Returns the updated number
def highestDigitTobeChanged(numberList):
    highestDigit = numberList[0]
    newHighestDigit = -1    
    # find the next highest number
    for i in range(len(numberList)):
        if highestDigit < numberList[i]:
            numberList = swapDigitAtInidix(0,i,numberList)          
    strNUmber = ''.join(numberList)
    strTemp = strNUmber[1:]
    strSorted = ''.join(sorted(strTemp))
    strNUmber = strNUmber[0] + strSorted
    return strNUmber
##### All Fucntions Defined #####


###### Start ######
print "Given Number:", number

##### Step1 #####
print "List without highest digit:",array_excpet_highest_digit
for i in range(len(str_excpet_highest_digit)-1):
  # Find the higest index.     
  if (array_excpet_highest_digit[i] < array_excpet_highest_digit[i+1]) and correct_Index == -1:
      correct_Index = i 
      correct_Digit = array_excpet_highest_digit[i]
      # swap the digit 
      array_excpet_highest_digit = swapDigitAtInidix(i,i+1,array_excpet_highest_digit)
      digit_Moved = array_excpet_highest_digit[i]     
      print "MOdified List without higest digit",array_excpet_highest_digit      
  # To check whether the new moved digit is the next bigger digit          
  elif (correct_Index != -1 ) and ( correct_Digit < array_excpet_highest_digit[i] and digit_Moved > array_excpet_highest_digit[i] ):
      array_excpet_highest_digit = swapDigitAtInidix(correct_Index,i,array_excpet_highest_digit)
      digit_Moved = array_excpet_highest_digit[correct_Index]
      print "MOdified List without higest digit",array_excpet_highest_digit      

  # To check whether the new moved digit is the next bigger digit. Apply this for the last element in the list                
  if (correct_Index != -1 ) and ( correct_Digit < array_excpet_highest_digit[i+1] and digit_Moved > array_excpet_highest_digit[i+1] ):
      array_excpet_highest_digit = swapDigitAtInidix(correct_Index,i+1,array_excpet_highest_digit)
      digit_Moved = array_excpet_highest_digit[correct_Index]
      print "MOdified List without higest digit",array_excpet_highest_digit      

##### Step2 #####
if correct_Index == -1:
    # Except the highest digit all other digits in decending order. Which means Step1 needs to be done.
    finalNumber = highestDigitTobeChanged(numberList)

else:
    # Create the remaining sorted list 
    array_excpet_highest_digit = sortRemainingList(correct_Index+1,array_excpet_highest_digit)
    tmpfinalString=''.join(array_excpet_highest_digit)
    finalNumber = int(stringArr[0] + tmpfinalString)

print "Next Higest Number:",  finalNumber
```

Please let me know if there are any better solutions.

Comment: This sounds like a programming contest question. Can you give a reference to the origin?

Comment: Google found this : http://thereq.com/q/151/technical-software-interview-question/next-highest-number-with-same-digits . Not sure if this is the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach **doesn't actually work**; for example, for `number = 217294` it gives the result as `221479` (what about `217429` or the other nine numbers between the two?)

---

Your code is not compliant with Python's [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [documentation conventions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), including the following:

1. `import` statements in the wrong order, not separated from the body of the code, and one isn't even used;
2. function and variable names not `lowercase_with_underscores` (or even consistent); and
3. block comments not in docstring form.

---

You could make much more use of function definitions; all that should run directly is something like the following, at the bottom of the script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import random # isn't needed by any other functions

    test = random.randint(999, 999999)
    print "Input number: {0}".format(test)
    result = find_next_highest(test)
    print "Next highest number with same digits: {0}".format(result)
```

This allows you to `import` your functions elsewhere without having to run anything. It would also make testing your code much easier if more of it were inside functions.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the correct way to name the functions, variables, modules etc.. in python ?

Comment: @python_lover that information is all in the style guide, to which I've provided a link in the answer